# Get HTML of rectangular region

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm wondering if anyone has any crazy ways to get the HTML of a rectangular region of the screen.

I can currently do it with `document.caretRangeFromPoint()` and then using `document.createRange()` and then `document.cloneContents()` which returns a `document-fragment` of HTML.

This is proving to be unreliable and can yield unexpected results (basically it's selecting text with an 'invisible' cursor and then getting the HTML of the selected text; it can sometimes select html in other close by areas of the window or doesn't select some elements, even though they're in the bounds I provided)

If anyone has any other ways of doing this I'd love to hear them

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Just because you asked for crazy. If you are not concerned about responsiveness, you could on onload map out your elements pretty easily and create an array of dimensions. Then when you draw your rectangle  via onmousendown & onmouseup crank through the array of dimensions to see if the rectangle overlaps any elements and then push it to a temporary array. The temp array is what you will preform what ever action you want. Hope this helps, if your create a jsfiddle I will write it out. Good luck!

p.s. problem is with slow devices their could be some lag depending how many elements are on the page. Also typed this from a surface so please excuse the less then verbose answer.

Comment: Interesting idea. What about if I want to get the contents of half and element. So if the rectangular region I want starts at the top of the div and finishes half way through.

Comment: Well lol LEts get crazy! I actaully just wrote out an idea similar which was executed superbly by @Jorg and  found here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22800040/a-more-efficient-javascript-code-for-a-highlighting-function/22800224#22800224. The difference is your span tags would be now checking to see if it fit inside of the square. This is really crazy just because think about the amount of work. First collect all the elements available then find all of their words changed to have individual span tags(at on load) and then determine if each span tag is in your square. This is interesting

Comment: If you want i will make jsfiddle showing idea. but if this is just a mind exercise i will let it be. :D Have Fun! I ran out of space in comment so had to make another D:

Answer (score 0):

Pressing F12 will bring up the error console in which there will be an icon that looks liek a magnifying glass, if you click that then click a HTML element on the page, it will take you to the selected area and present you the code.