# A more efficient JavaScript code for a highlighting function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays, function

So this is the functionality I need to clean up:

I need to create a function where viewers can click on any word in a sentence, and it will be highlighted. However, I need to make it so only one word is highlighted at a time. So for example, if you click the word 'you' and then you change your mind and click the word 'eagle', then the word 'you' will be deselected.

There's already existing code for it, but we're working on a very tight deadline and if we make edits and adjustments using this extremely long, extremely difficult-to-navigate code, then we will use up so many precious weeks producing a single 5-minute interactivity.

This is what it looks like:
[image: http://bit.ly/PeKOxH]

And this is a snippet of the JS (so you can glimpse the problem):
[image: http://bit.ly/PeMY0l]

(the HTML and JS codes are available upon request)

So instead of this long hell that we might need to put ourselves through, I was thinking something like passing each sentence through an array so each individual word would already be assigned to a name. So then we would be able to call each array via a for loop to print it out on the page, and use an arrayName[i] to call individual words for highlighting. And then maybe an if-else statement so only the selected word is highlighted.

I've been trying to push the actual HTML elements through the arrays, like, only get the `<p>` for every `<div id="sentence1">` or something, but it doesn't seem to be possible... If it is, please tell me how it is done, or if it is not, I will still appreciate any other alternative for this.

I cannot for the life of me figure out all the hard-coding on my own, as I only know so much about JavaScript right now, but am very, very willing to learn! Any help with this would be deeply appreciated, as we're working on a very tight deadline.

Thank you so much in advance! Please, any help, or any suggestions would do!

**EDIT**

This is the code for our `checkAns()` function. It increments `var correct` when a correct answer is highlighted every time `checkAns()` runs. It is also responsible for marking specific numbers wrong or right.

```
function checkAns(){
    document.getElementById('alertMsg').style.visibility = "hidden";


    if(Ans1B == "selected"){
        correct++
        document.getElementById('marksymbol1').className = "smile";
    }
    else
    {
        document.getElementById('marksymbol1').className = "sad";
    }
    if(Ans2A == "selected"){
        correct++
        document.getElementById('marksymbol2').className = "smile";
    }
    else
    {
        document.getElementById('marksymbol2').className = "sad";
    }
    if(Ans3A == "selected"){
        correct++
        document.getElementById('marksymbol3').className = "smile";
    }
    else
    {
        document.getElementById('marksymbol3').className = "sad";
    }
    if(Ans4A == "selected"){
        correct++
        document.getElementById('marksymbol4').className = "smile";
    }
    else
    {
        document.getElementById('marksymbol4').className = "sad";
    }
    if(Ans5A == "selected"){
        correct++
        document.getElementById('marksymbol5').className = "smile";
    }
    else
    {
        document.getElementById('marksymbol5').className = "sad";
    }
```

Comment: How do you know which answer is correct? Is it available in the HTML markup, or does it only exist in the JS?

Comment: @Wheeyls: It only exists in the JS. Added an edit for you so you can see the `checkAns()` function :)

Comment: Do you have jQuery or another DOM util library available to you?

Comment: @Wheeyls: I have jquery-1.9.1 and jquery-ui :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per @DrewGoldsBerry's answer, with some example code. Here's a working fiddle of the code below: http://jsfiddle.net/E3D6T/1/

Set up your HTML with a class to indicate which lines should have the highlight functionality.

```
<p class="highlight">Each word will be wrapped in a span.</p>
<p class="highlight">A second paragraph here.</p>
```

In your JS, split the `p` elements into words wrapped in `span` tags, which can then be bound to a click function:

```
// wrap words in spans
$('p.highlight').each(function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.html($this.text().replace(/\b(\w+)\b/g, "<span>$1</span>"));
});

// bind to each span
$('p.highlight span').click(function () {
    $(this).parent().find('span').css('background-color', '');
    $(this).css('background-color', '#ffff66');
});
```

edit:

http://jsfiddle.net/jorgthuijls/E3D6T/16/

I added all the answer checking to the click function itself. Should be fairly straight forward.

Comment: Thank you so much for this code!!! You have no idea how much this helps!! But is it possible to check answers with this? Like check if the correct spans have that particular css and increment a `var correct` for each correct span that's highlighted?

Answer (score 2):

Sorry to add to the noise... my answer is very similar to Jorgs and Roberts, and it also checks for valid answers.

JS Fiddle is here:

http://jsfiddle.net/M7faZ/3/

The checkAns function uses the ID of the sentence element, to map the `answer` object to the `selectedAnswer` object.

The HTML has carefully chosen ID and classnames:

```
<ul class='sentences'>
  <li class='sentence' id='ans1'>Can you draw an eagle?</li>
  <li class='sentence' id='ans2'>She is good in painting.</li>
</ul>

<div id='mark-symbol-ans1'></div>
<div id='mark-symbol-ans2'></div>
```

And the JS has a map of answers.

```
// get the list
var $sentences = $('.sentence'),
    answers = {
        ans1: 'you',
        ans2: 'She'
    },
    selectedAnswers = {};

function checkAns() {
    var correct;

    for (var i in answers) {
        correct = selectedAnswers[i] === answers[i]

        $('#mark-symbol-' + i).toggleClass('smile', correct);
        $('#mark-symbol-' + i).toggleClass('sad', !correct);
    }
}
```

If you care about people cheating, this part should be done on the server so it's not exposed to the client.

Comment: Sorry, I linked to an old version... gimme a sec.

Answer (score 1):

This could maybe work if the amount of content is limited else you might experience some lag onload.

Start out by gathering all the elements that need this ability into an array. Split each sentence using " " as the variable into another temporary  array. Step through temp array adding a span tag around each word with a new class. Then return the new string with span tags to the corresponding element. This can be down with 2 for loops. Last bind both hover and onclick to each new tag by using another for loop. Sorry no code, I'm watching tosh lol, but if you make a jsfiddle I will write it for you.

Like I said this shouldn't be done with a lot of sentences at one time. You could always stagger sentences if you have multiple sections.

Hope this helps explain how I would do it. Good luck let me know what happens!

Comment: If you need to check answers in my solution you would just pass the word selected instead of a special numbers. Makes it easier in some ways because its not using codes.

Answer (score 1):

A similar solution to Jorg's, with some variations. I've done the wrapping with split() and join() instead of regex. I also tend to put my jQuery chains on separate lines for visual clarity.

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript"> 

    $( document ).ready( function() {
        var p = $( "p", "#myDiv" );
        $.each( p, function( i, obj ){
            $( obj )
                .attr( "class", "highlightable" );
            obj.innerHTML = "<span>" + obj.innerHTML.split(" ").join( "</span> <span>" ) + "</span>";
        });

        $( ".highlightable span", "#myDiv" )
            .on( "click", function(){
                $( "span", $( this ).parent() )
                    .css( "background-color", "");
                $( this )
                    .css( "background-color", "#ffff45" );
            });
    });
</script>

</head>
<body>

<div id="myDiv">
    <p>Here is a sentence.</p>
    <p>Here is another sentence.</p>
    <p>Here is yet another sentence.</p>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```